# How to allow Magento to be accessed by anybody in my LAN?

Tags: magento2, localhost, hosting

Im running Magento 2.1.7 on Red Hat Enterprise 7. I have to allow everybody in the LAN to be able to access the website and I have done the following :

in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` , `Listen 80` is changed to `Listen 8080` and

`<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

as well as

`<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

and

`<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

I have looked few of the help available but mostly they are for WAMP. I'm not sure what the differences are because its working on WAMP with these settings. Computers in the same LAN is unable to connect on the LAMP and the Magento backend is inaccessible. It returns a Page not found error.

Please advice on what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Update your secure and unsecure **base url** with your IP instead of **localhost**.

ie. If your IP is `192.168.1.10` then your base url will be `http://192.168.1.10/magento`.

Anyone from the same network will be able to access the website after this change.

Comment: hi, is there any configuration I need to do on httpd.conf, or do i just leave it at the default state?

Comment: not necessary. updating base url itself solve the problem